# Cannot grant access to Compute Service Agent in Firebase Stripe payment integration

Tags: firebase, stripe-payments

I am trying to intergrade stripe into my application and am on the setup page. The 3rd tab "Review access granted to this extension," asks me to grant access to "Compute Service Agent". When I try to give it access by clicking the button, it goes into the loading state and disappears. There is no way to move to the next step without giving it access so I am stuck at this stage

Before
[image]

After
[image]